# HTML: What is the tag used for sub-dividing content area?

Tags: html

Quick question:

What is the tag called for sub-dividing content area?  Not for images, but for html content that with a title.  There is a specific tag for this, but I forgot what it is called.

[image]

Comment: It's a `<fieldset>`. The title is provided by a `<legend>` tag

Comment: <div> ? or <fieldset><legend>Title</legend><stuff></stuff></fieldset> ?

Comment: Fieldset is indeed correct, thanks for the answers everyone.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you after `<fieldset>`?

http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/fieldset

Answer (score 2):

A `fieldset`.

```
<fieldset>
   <legend> Title </legend>
   // content
</fieldset>
```